# Mock an exception when calling method inside method

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

I have this code and I want to throw an IOException with mockito when the close method inside the try block is called

```
public static void cleanup(Logger log, Closeable... closeables) {
        for (Closeable c : closeables) {
            if (c != null) {
                try {
                    c.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    if (log != null) {
                        log.warn("Exception in closing " + c, e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is what I tried inside a test method, but clearly it doesn't work:

```
OutputStream outputStream = Mockito.mock(OutputStream.class);
doThrow(new IOException()).when(outputStream).close();

cleanup(log, closeables);
```

How can I accomplish my goal? Thanks!

Comment: Could you add your test please? And explain a bit more what `it doesn't work` means

Comment: The exception is not thrown by c.close, I am stuck at this point the only other thing in my test is an array of Outpustream

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you pass the **mock** as 2nd argument to `cleanup` method.

The following test works for me:

```java
    @Test
    public void testException() throws IOException {
        OutputStream outputStream = Mockito.mock(OutputStream.class);
        doThrow(new IOException()).when(outputStream).close();
        cleanup(log, outputStream);

        Mockito.verify(outputStream, times(1)).close(); // make sure #close method is called once
    }
```

The `cleanup` method looks right. No changes required.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a little bit of research on the usage of `doThrow(new Exception())` in the Javadoc Mockito documentation. [This passage](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.6.28/org/mockito/Mockito.html#stubbing) of the core documentation tells me that in order to have an exception thrown by a stubbed object, the syntax is `when(yourStub.method()).doThrow(new Exception())` for functions returning void and `when(yourStub.method()).thenThrow(new Exception())` for methods returning anything other than void. In short, the call to configure the throwing of the exception should be `when(outputStream.close()).doThrow(new IOException())`.

Additionally, you need to pass your outputStream as the second argument into the cleanup function as Petr points out in his answer. Also, the cleanup function might need refactoring to take a single Closable rather than a collection of Closables if you plan to pass a single Closable to it, like you are in your question.